# Configuration to a hidden IPv6 network via wireless

Tags: networking, wireless, ipv6

I am trying to configure to a new router that requires a IPv6 connection, I managed to connect via ethernet modifying the interface file but I have big troubles in connecting via wireless. Could you help?

I am new into ubuntu and know very little about networks and ubuntu itself, please keep the explanation simple, I very appreciate any help.

Here it is the interface configuration I have managed to create.

```
    # interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
# The loopback network interface

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface (eth0)
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

# The primary network interface (wlan0)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp

# IPv6 Address Blocks
# Add a static block for your default public IPv6 address, and include a directive for its gateway.

iface eth0 inet6 static
    address 2001:db8:a0b:12f0::1/64
    gateway fe80::1

iface lo inet loopback
address fe80::b0b5:4cfb:ef29:2f98/64
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.0.21
broadcast 192.168.1.255
gateway 192.168.1.15

# add an additional block for each IPv6 address you need to configure.

iface eth0 inet6 static
    address 2001:db8:2000:aff0::1/64

iface wlan0 inet6 static
    address 2001:db8:2000:aff0::2/64
```

Comment: This is possibly the most confusing `/etc/network/interfaces` that I have ever seen and I've seen some real beauties! Are you simply trying to get an IPv6 address from the router? If so, must it be static? A very simple interfaces file will get both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses by DHCP.

Comment: Absolutely not, it does not need to be static at all! it has to work and for me if you write nonsense and make it work, it is perfectly fine. Unfortunately I am not skilled in this yet, and as far I am concern I just need it done asap to carry on with my job. @chili555 I am all ears!

Comment: UPDATE: I believe that thanks to a reboot the wireless started working.... damn me.. now the only connection that does not work is the 5 ghz one

Comment: UPDATE: the output of 'wlist channel' does not produce any 5.0 ghz results I believe my computer does not support that networking connection..

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to configure to the 2.4hz wireless connection. After updating the `/etc/network/interfaces`. I must have rebooted the system....

Anyhow here it is the code

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
# The loopback network interface

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface (eth0)
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

# IPv6 Address Blocks
# Add a static block for your default public IPv6 address, and include a directive for its gateway.

iface eth0 inet6 static
    address 2001:db8:a0b:12f0::1/64
    gateway fe80::1

# add an additional block for each IPv6 address you need to configure.

iface eth0 inet6 static
    address 2001:db8:2000:aff0::1/64
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the `/etc/network/interfaces` that I suggest you use:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-ssid <your_essid>
wpa-psk <your_wpa_key>
```

Reboot. Check to see if you got an IP address:

```
ip addr show
```

Ideally, it reads something like this:

```
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether xx:c5:d4:0e:64:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.10/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global wlp3s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 2602:306:b8c8:15f9:ece1:521:3e13:68ca/64 scope global temporary dynamic 
       valid_lft 604770sec preferred_lft 86086sec
    inet6 2602:306:b8c8:15f9:5ec5:d4ff:fe0e:64a6/64 scope global mngtmpaddr dynamic 
       valid_lft 2591970sec preferred_lft 604770sec
    inet6 fe80::5ec5:d4ff:fe0e:64a6/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

As you can see, the router gives an inet6 address; in my example 2602:306:b8c8:15f9:ece1:521:3e13:68ca/64.

Check to see if you can ping:

```
ping6 -c3 www.att.com
```